# Buddypress Group Activity Loop Filter activity type

Tags: loop, filters, buddypress

I'm using Buddypress 1.8.1

When the group home page load I want to show only 'activity_update' and 'joined_group' activities in Activity Loop.

Here is my Activity Loop code. It is standard loop code.

```
<?php if ( bp_has_activities( bp_ajax_querystring( 'activity' ) ) ) : ?>
    <?php while ( bp_activities() ) : bp_the_activity(); ?>

        <?php locate_template( array( 'activity/entry.php' ), true, false ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How to filter these activities in page load. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this function in bp-custom.php page.

```
function filtering_activity_default( $query ) {
  if ( empty( $query ) && empty( $_POST ) ) {
    $query = 'action=activity_update,joined_group';
  }
  return $query;
}

add_filter( 'bp_ajax_querystring', 'filtering_activity_default', 999 );
```

This is working for me as expected.